# Confused on log levels in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I am trying to find out what are the differences between log levels. If I do:

```
logger.warn 'TEST LOGGER'
```

and

```
logger.debug 'TEST LOGGER'
```

I see the exact same information in my log file. What is the difference between each of those levels?

Comment: Depends on what you defined in your environment file (ex: config/environments/development.rb). If you defined `config.log_level = :warn`, then `logger.debug "something"` will not log because it is "lower" than a warn

Answer (score 0):

As MrYoshiji said in the comments... log levels are just used to determine which statements should appear in the logs based on the `config.log_level` settings. The [Rails Guide on Log Levels](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels) explains it well... Here is a screenshot of the relevant information:

[image: Rails Log Levels]